# Text Shadow on links in Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, shadow

I know `text-shadow` do not work in Internet Explorer, but their own filter for shadow should work. But it do not seems to work in links (`<a>Link</a>`). Any work around?

[image]

```
/*Works*/
#navigation .nav li {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#000000,direction=180,strength=3);

}
```

[image]

```
/*Do not work*/
#navigation .nav li a {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#000000,direction=180,strength=3);
}
```

[image]

```
/*Text-shadow in Google Chrome working and what I want to achive*/
#navigation .nav li a {
    text-shadow: 0 2px 2px #000;
}
```

Problem with adding effect on the list is that it adds the shadow to everything, not just the text, and it looks awful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap text in the link in `<span>` and attach shadow to it.

Comment: Hum... so I must attach shadow on `<span>` instead of `<a>`? That is annoying since I cannot edit the `<li>` :P

Comment: okay, attach to <A>, but put padding on <li>, you would get you shadow, but loose the big hover-action area, sorry mate there is no other way

Answer (score 1):

```
#navigation .nav li a span {
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#000000,direction=180,strength=3);
}
```

Then:

```
<a href="#"><span>Link Text Here</span></a>
```

That should target just the text.